# replaceFirst does not work, but replace works on the exact same input?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a program where a portion of it needs to replace part of the string without deleting duplicates so I am using replaceFirst() which is not working properly.

INPUT:

```
lock: "O_2_^-^"
str:  " O_2_^-^ "
```

CODE:

```
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(lock);
System.out.println(str.contains(lock));
str = str.replaceFirst(lock, "");
System.out.println(str);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 O_2_^-^ 
O_2_^-^
true
 O_2_^-^
```

The above is real output from my program. Though the replace() method will not work for my current situation I did test it and the output is compeletely different, as in correct.

INPUT:

```
lock: "O_2_^-^"
str:  " O_2_^-^ "
```

CODE:

```
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(lock);
System.out.println(str.contains(lock));
str = str.replace(lock, "");
System.out.println(str);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 O_2_^-^ 
O_2_^-^
true
  //empty line of output because string was detected and removed.
```

I have tried everything outside of writing my own replaceFirst() method, if anyone has any advice or input that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `replaceFirst`'s 1st parameter is assumed to be a regex, you need to escape special characters. If you do not know beforehand what `lock` is going to be (example coming from user-input), you can use `Pattern.quote(lock)` to escape it.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/4Iyoii)**.

Answer (score 5):

[`replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes regex as a parameter, use this:

```
String lock = "O_2_\\^-\\^";
```

---

```
String lock = "O_2_\\^-\\^";
String str = " O_2_^-^ "; 
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(lock);
System.out.println(str.contains(lock));
str = str.replaceFirst(lock, "");
System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
O_2_^-^ 
O_2_\^-\^
false
```

Comment: +1. You might want to add an explanation about escaping these characters.

Answer (score 4):

`replaceFirst` expects a regular expression. So you need to escape your string accordingly.

PS: If your String to replace is dynamic, you can use `Pattern.quote(String)` to escape it for you.

Comment: Specifically, ^ is the beginning of the line.